# MySQL Installer command line

Tags: installation, mysql

I try to change the installation directory of mysql-installer-web-community-5.7.16.0.msi.

I install it from command line with :

> msiexec INSTALLLOCATION="C:\" /i
>   mysql-installer-web-community-5.7.16.0.msi

When i try to run the MySQL Installer, I have the error :

> Internal error. (Your installation appears to be damaged. You should uninstall and reinstall MySQL Installer for Windows). The installer will now close.

Comment: Did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839978/install-msi-with-msiexec-in-a-specific-directory? If yes pelase close this as dup.

Comment: Yes i try but the software was not installed in the right folder...

Comment: Using `C:\` is a horrible idea. It might have an internal check that prevents you from using the root directory. In addition what do you mean it didn't install into the right folder? What should your end result look like and what did you end up with by using your solution so far?

Comment: I try to install in a folder in the desktop but I have the same error. With INSTALLOCATION, the software was installed in the folder that I told, but I have this error. And with TARGETDIR, the software does not installed in the PATH that I sepcified

Comment: The result that I want : I want to install the software by command line in the path that I choose. And I want to use it from the path that I specified in the installation. With INSTALLOCATION, I install it in the specified PATH but I can't use it due to the internal error...